# Is it possible to return an integer to the main function from a unsigned char data type function?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have this `unsigned char` *sumBinaryFigure* function that calculates the sum of the digits of the binary representation of an `unsigned long long` number. When I call this function from the main function, for an `unsigned long long` it should return a integer(or another numeric data type) although the data type of the function is `unsigned char`. Is it possible? I tried a function overloading and it didn't work. If it sounds absurd, it's not my fault.

```
unsigned char sumBinaryFigure(unsigned long long number)
{
  unsigned int S = 0;   

  while (number)
  {
    S += number % 2;
    number /= 2;
  }

return S;
}
```

Comment: "it should return a integer although the data type of the function is unsigned char. Is it possible?".  Ummm... No. If the function returns an `unsigned char`, that's what it returns.

Comment: Why should the function return a value of a type other than its return type?  Assuming the usual sizes, where both `long long` types are 64 bits, "the sum of the digits of the binary representation of an `unsigned long long`" will be in the range of `0..64`, which easily fits in any of the `char` types.  Is there some other reason that you specifically need its return type to be `int`?  Is it part of a set of overloads for various types, for example?

Comment: Also, note that the `char` types are considered integral types, which means that they are treated as 1-byte integers which may or may not represent a single character.  `uint8_t` is usually a typedef of `unsigned char`, and `int8_t` is usually a typedef of `signed char`, for example.

Comment: `unsigned char` is an integer type, your code already does what you are requesting.

Comment: @JustinTime, it's what I am asked to do. E.g. if the function is called for 11, the sumBinaryFigure is 3 (1+0+1+1) and it should return to main the 3 as a number, not as the third character in ASCII without changing the data type of the function and I do not control the call of the function from the main. So, how do I do it to get a 3 (as a number), not as the 3rd character in ASCII?

Comment: Ah.  Just use `unsigned char`, then.  `char` is an integer type that can be read as either a number or a character, and pulls triple duty as "ASCII character for current code page", "UTF-8 Unicode code unit", and "single-byte integer"; what any value stored in it is interpreted as depends on the context.  For example, assuming `char c = 'A';`, and assuming either ASCII or Unicode, `c` will actually contain the number `65`.  Then, `std::cout << c;` will output `A`, while `int i = 2 * c;` will assign `130` to `i`.  See [here](http://ideone.com/lwkNoy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I call this function from the main function, for an unsigned long long it should return a integer although the data type of the function is unsigned char. Is it possible?

Yes.  The question is not absurd, C types are just confusing.  `unsigned char` and `int` both represent integers.

*Your code is correct.*

---

`unsigned char` is a 1-byte datatype.  It can be used to represent a letter, or it can be used to represent a number.

The following statements are equivalent.

```
unsigned char ch = 'A';
unsigned char ch = 65;
```

Whether you use `unsigned char` as a character or integer, the machine does not care.

**`char` does not necessarily contain a character.  It also represents  small numbers**

The posted implementation of `sumBinaryFigure` returns a number in the range of 0-255, nothing wrong with that.  Because a `long long` is almost certainly less than 256 bits, you don't need to worry about `unsigned char` not being large enough.

---

If I can suggest one change to your program in order to make it less confusing, change this line

```
unsigned int S = 0;
```

to this...

```
unsigned char S = 0;
```

---

#### Addendum

Just to be clear, consider the following code.

```
int main (void) {
  char ch_num = 65;   // ch_num  is the byte 0100 0001
  char ch_char = 'A'; // ch_char is the byte 0100 0001

  printf ("%d\n", ch_num);  // Prints 65
  printf ("%d\n", ch_char); // Prints 65

  printf ("%c\n", ch_num);  // Prints A
  printf ("%c\n", ch_char); // Prints A
}
```

A `char` is a byte.  It's a sequence of bits with no meaning except what we impose on it.

That byte can be *interpreted* as either a number or character, but that decision is up to the programmer.  The `%c` format specifier says "interpret this as a character.  The `%d` format specifier says "interpret this as a number".

Whether it's an integer or character is decided by the output function, not the data type.

Comment: nit-pick - `'A'` isn't guaranteed to equal `65`.

Comment: @QuestionC, then if the BinaryFigure for 11 is 1011 (`sumBinaryFigure` is =3), how can I make it return to the main function the 3 as number 3, not the 3rd character in ASCII?

Comment: @Skyp89 It _is_ returned as  the number `3`.  `char` types just have the distinction that the number stored in them can be interpreted as either a raw number or a character's ASCII/UTF-8 code, depending on the context.

Comment: @QuestionC, but when I call the function sumBinaryFigure(11) I would like to have a 3 printed on the screen, not the 3rd simbol in ASCII

Comment: The value printed is determined by how you print the value.  It's not a property of the data type.  The only difference between a `char` and `int` is how much memory they use.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char` can be converted to `int` without narrowing on all platforms that I can think of. You don't need to overload anything, just assign the result of the function to an `int` variable:

```
int popcnt = sumBinaryFigure(1023);
```

In fact, taking the function semantics into account, there's no way the result value will not fit into an `int`, which is guaranteed to be at least 16-bit, which means the minimal `numeric_limits<int>::max()` value is 32767. You'd have to have a datatype capable of storing over 32767 binary digits for this to be even remotely possible (`int` on most platforms is 32-bit)

Comment: You didn't get the idea. From main somebody asks for sumBinaryFigure(1023). Whatever I would do in the `sumBinaryFigure` when it returns the value to the main function, it will be a `char`because of the function data type.

Comment: `unsigned char` is an arithmetic data type and it converts implicitly to `int`. You can return `unsigned char` from `sumBinaryFigure` and assign the result to `int`.

Comment: @Skyp89 maybe I don't understand your question, but here's a [live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s4v5MmaNkHe0e29b).

Comment: i have no control on the main function. Just on the `sumBinaryFigure` or I could try to create another function to help me acomplish this.

Comment: Okay, then what do you have control over? `unsigned char` is a numeric data type (although it gets special handling for iostreams) so you're already returning something fitting your description. If you can change `sumBinaryFigure` just declare it to return an `int`.

Comment: I'm not allowed :)

Comment: Okay, let me get the facts straight: You can't change `main`, which calls `sumBinaryFigure`. And you can't change `sumBinaryFigure`?

Comment: Nothing in the main and I can not change the data type of the function. You can do things inside of it.

Comment: But the inside is already correct. Unless you mean the parameter type. Then change the return type. But I still posit that everything is correct.